# howto configure /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.shlibs

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I created a debian package for the mongo c++ driver (see https://launchpad.net/~28msec/+archive/utils/+sourcepub/2616490/+listing-archive-extra). But one really important file is missing in the package. The shlibs file located at /var/lib/dpkg/info/.
Now, I googled like crazy to figure out how I can tell the debian packaging mechanism to create this shlibs file. But I am not able to do it. Does someone know how this file needs to be configured?

I checked out other packages. E.g. in libarchive, when executing the command dh_makeshlibs -v, I see the following:
rm -f debian/libarchive-dev/DEBIAN/shlibs
    rm -f debian/libarchive12/DEBIAN/shlibs
    echo 'libarchive 12 libarchive12' >>debian/libarchive12/DEBIAN/shlibs
    echo "# Automatically added by dh_makeshlibs">> debian/libarchive12.postinst.debhelper
    sed "" /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postinst-makeshlibs >> debian/libarchive12.postinst.debhelper
    echo '# End automatically added section' >> debian/libarchive12.postinst.debhelper
    echo "# Automatically added by dh_makeshlibs"> debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper.new
    sed "" /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postrm-makeshlibs >> debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper.new
    echo '# End automatically added section' >> debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper.new
    cat debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper >> debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper.new
    mv debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper.new debian/libarchive12.postrm.debhelper
    chmod 644 debian/libarchive12/DEBIAN/shlibs
    chown 0:0 debian/libarchive12/DEBIAN/shlibs
    (grep -s -v misc:Pre-Depends debian/libarchive12.substvars; echo misc:Pre-Depends=multiarch-support) > debian/libarchive12.substvars.new
    mv debian/libarchive12.substvars.new debian/libarchive12.substvars
    rm -f debian/bsdtar/DEBIAN/shlibs
    rm -f debian/bsdcpio/DEBIAN/shlibs

Where are all these commands comming from? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The `dh_makeshlibs` debhelper tool should take care of that for you, probably under the `binary-arch` rule. You are using debhelper, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using the debhelper. So, I don't have to add an <package-name>.shlip file to the debian directory?

Comment: Right. If `dh_makeshlibs` is being called at the right point in your build process, then it will scan for any shared libraries in your debian/$packagename build directory, and then put the appropriate calls to `ldconfig` in the postinst and prerm for the new package so that the .shlibs file will be generated at the right time.

Comment: And if this doesn't work? Do you know how I can debug it? Here is my rules file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8afawa1r0829mv/rules . Would be awesome if you could take a look!

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems there. Would you mind uploading the rest of the package source somewhere?

Comment: Sure! Here are the links: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3p7jkfyn4mz4ns/libmongo-cxx-driver_2.0.7%7Eprecise8.debian.tar.gz https://www.dropbox.com/s/2e89axrjte5byx5/libmongo-cxx-driver_2.0.7%7Eprecise8.orig.tar.gz